# config sentinel to work with "public/index.php" in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have install Laravel in my VPS, and it's working with the "public/index.php" in the url. I had tried lot more to remove this from url but all are failed, and I have to work with this. Currently I am working on the Sentinel authorization package. It's installed successfully but after login or when i click on the sentinal logo I always get redirected to the "http://myipaddress/tmb/" which is incorrect, so where I can set the home link so that it goes to the "http://myipaddress/tmb/public/index.php/". My laravel version is 5.1.20

Answer (score 0):

The default config for the target URLs is the 'home' route. So you have to setup this route in your `routes.php` properly.

You can override the default routes in the `config/sentinel.php` file.

But anyway, it's very dangerous that anyone can access your whole application code directory. You should either forbid access to all resources which are not in /public directory or (much better) configure/ask your VPS to set the document root to your public directory!